# How to update from OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 to OS X Sierra 10.12?

Tags: macos

I need to update my MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2008):

[image]

from OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan) to OS X 10.12 (Sierra) due to an incompatibility with [Traktor](https://www.native-instruments.com/en/catalog/traktor/):

[image: ][1]]

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid your 2008 MacBook Pro can't update to 10.12. That OS doesn't support your hardware.

You'll need to find an older version of the NI software.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would upgrade a mac from 10.11 to 10.12.

1. Make a good backup - decide if Time Machine is good enough or you need a bootable clone.
2. Open the App Store app from this guide and install the upgraded OS.

   - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208202

As pointed out, if your machine doesn’t meet the requirements, you would need to find virtualization software that runs on your hardware and run the newer OS or use your backup to load your data and programs on newer hardware.